# Defining Empirical Risk Minimization

Tags: estimation, risk

I am reading [Machine Learning - A probabilistic Perspective](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262018020) by Kevin Murphy and in chapter 6.5 the author discusses [Empirical Risk Minimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization), and provides the following definition:

$p_*(\mathbf{x}, y) \approx p_{\text{emp}} (\mathbf{x}, y) = \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_i \delta_{\mathbf{x}_i}(\mathbf{x})\delta_{y_i}(y)$

and then defines the empirical risk as follows:

$R_{\text{emp}}(D, D)  = R(p_{\text{emp}}, \delta) = \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_i  L(y_i) \delta(\mathbf{x}_i)$

I am having a hard time understanding the two formulas above, but mostly, what is the difference between $\delta_{\mathbf{x}_i}(\mathbf{x})$, $\delta_{y_i}(y)$, and $\delta ({\mathbf{x}_i}) $?